# Redux Toolkit with useRef - Can someone explain my code to me?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, use-ref

I'm looking back over one of my old personal projects which uses Redux Toolkit, and I've come across some code where I can't explain exactly what it's doing:

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export let squaresRef;

const GameBoard = () => {
  const squares = useSelector(state => state.gameBoard.squares);
  squaresRef = useRef(squares);
  squaresRef.current = squares;
```

I remember writing this code, and it was because `squares` wasn't always the latest state, where as calling `squaresRef.current` was.

So instead of using `useSelector`, in other files I imported `squaresRef` and called `squaresRef.current`.

The commit message I made when I updated my code was `Use squaresRef rather than squares to ensure latest gameboard`; not very helpful.

I've spent the last hour looking over my search history from when this commit was made, and there's nothing in there, and Googling hasn't helped either.

I know that the outcome of writing the code this way was that it fixed `squares` not always being the latest version, but I cannot figure-out why this code fixed it.

Can anyone explain to me why `squaresRef.current` is always up to date with the latest state, but `squares` isn't?

Comment: Can you show where did you use `squaresRef` and `sqaures`

Comment: One scenario I can think of: When something async (often `setTimeout` or `setInterval`) is triggered from a component, you sometimes have the issue that the state from `useSelector` is outdated because you're using the value that's captured in a closure of a callback, rather than the updated value. As in: the value at the time is "frozen" when the function is defined. But when the function is actually executing (possible much later), you would need to "refresh" the state. Accessing the ref fixes this.

Comment: @timotgl Thanks for this, I think that you're right. `squaresRef.current` is called from a hook that is called from within a `setTimeout()` function, so that would make sense!