# How to use a dynamic variable in useEffect which works once when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am using socket.io on reactjs. There aren't any problems. Everything is working as expected.

I use it like this:

```
const [username,setUsername]=useState<string>('')
useEffect(() => {
        server.on("CORRECT_USERNAME_TO_LOGIN",(socketId: string) => {
          dispatch(authActions.setUsername(username))
          navigate(ROUTER_PATHS.activeUsers)
        })
}, [])
```

If the server emit to *CORRECT_USERNAME_TO_LOGIN* channel, this code structure works well. Bu there is a status. *username* variable is a dynamic value I have to use it when the server emit to the channel. But the username variable isn't current value it is initial value when the server emit. Is this because I use it in useEffect ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the scope of the `CORRECT_USERNAME_TO_LOGIN` listener function. You can fix this by used `useRef`, which will be outside the React's state.
Example:
I am assuming you are getting the username through an API call.

```
// declare userNameRef
const userNameRef = useRef();

...
// this is a callback function from an API
(data) => {
   // we are assuming that data has the username
   userNameRef.current = data;
}

...
// inside the useEffect use it like the following

useEffect(() => {
        server.on("CORRECT_USERNAME_TO_LOGIN",(socketId: string) => {
          dispatch(authActions.setUsername(userNameRef.current))
          navigate(ROUTER_PATHS.activeUsers)
        })
}, [])
```

Comment: Okay, if you get a variable on the redux, should I use the ref feature again? Are there other ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Get a reference to your state variable so you can always access it's current value using the reference:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

// ...

const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('')
const usernameRef = useRef(username)

// ...

useEffect(() => {
    server.on("CORRECT_USERNAME_TO_LOGIN",(socketId: string) => {
      dispatch(authActions.setUsername(usernameRef.current))
      navigate(ROUTER_PATHS.activeUsers)
    })
}, [])
```

You can update `usernameRef` like:

```js
usernameRef.current = 'new-username'
```

wherever you're currently updating

Comment: Okay, if you get a variable on the redux, should I use the ref feature again? Are there other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Found this question for it https://stackoverflow.com/q/72112265/14628358. Though there aren't any answers, it's clearly stated that redux works with useRef. I don't know of other ways to solve this problem, since this approach always works and I don't look further I suppose.